# Combining two columns in two different rows in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, bootstrap-4

I have 2 rows each consists of 3 columns. each column is of class `.col-lg-4 .col-md-4 .col-sm-12`. I want to do a trick where I can combine two vertically aligned columns (*The one containing the image and the one above*) so that it is only one column. Is it even possible.

[image: Combinne]

**Code:**

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="services">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <p><i class="fa fa-bandcamp" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum voluptate vitae vel necessitatibus in ut modi eligendi labore, fuga quaerat libero dignissimos, optio dolore, facere, nostrum quidem culpa laboriosam eveniet.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <p><i class="fa fa-bandcamp" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore ipsam quibusdam illum porro labore adipisci asperiores totam aut eaque excepturi aliquid, esse inventore laborum dolorem ipsum error harum vero, quasi.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <p><i class="fa fa-bandcamp" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi, aliquam ipsa veritatis optio nihil expedita quia dolore sint officiis cumque. Ab quae, aspernatur saepe vitae reiciendis incidunt commodi dolorem amet!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <p><i class="fa fa-bandcamp" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam fugit nisi fuga dolore expedita. Amet libero quas provident assumenda vitae inventore nisi maxime beatae distinctio porro. Enim dicta qui quos!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <img src="assets/imgs/cats4-compressor.jpg" alt="Image" id="services-image">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest the columns like this...

https://www.codeply.com/go/TQa9DOZk2w

```
     <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-bandcamp" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum voluptate vitae vel necessitatibus in ut modi eligendi labore, fuga quaerat libero dignissimos, optio dolore, facere, nostrum quidem culpa laboriosam eveniet.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-bandcamp" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore ipsam quibusdam illum porro labore adipisci asperiores totam aut eaque excepturi aliquid, esse inventore laborum dolorem ipsum error harum vero, quasi.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-bandcamp" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi, aliquam ipsa veritatis optio nihil expedita quia dolore sint officiis cumque. Ab quae, aspernatur saepe vitae reiciendis incidunt commodi dolorem amet!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-bandcamp" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam fugit nisi fuga dolore expedita. Amet libero quas provident assumenda vitae inventore nisi maxime beatae distinctio porro. Enim dicta qui quos!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <img src="//placehold.it/300x500" alt="Image" id="services-image">
            </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its what you are looking for but bootstrap has push/pull/offset properties that allow you to manipulate how the grids are displayed.

```css
.col-lg-4 {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.col-sm-4 {
  background-color: darkred;
  height: 400px;
  border: red 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push-4">
        Hello
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push-4">
        Hello
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push-4">
        Hello
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-push-4">
        Hello
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    hello
  </div>

</div>
```

Hope this helps! (move the width of the screen wider if they stack)
https://jsfiddle.net/xnp3wwbh/

Answer (score -1):

It's just a matter of reorganizing the way that you have put the grid together. Separate the first two columns as col-sm-8 and col-sm-4 and then break the rows off inside the col-sm-8 from there.

Comment: Can you clarify your answer more so I can get your idea?

Answer (score -1):

I think your best best would to make all 6 'squares' a single row and make each column a third (col-md-4).